# Qt read QML data from file

Tags: qt, file, model

So I have *data.txt* where data like this:

```
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "0"; height: "-700.114"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "1"; height: "-698.214"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "2"; height: "-695.955"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "3"; height: "-706.116"; }
    [...]
```

and I need to add this data to *Data.qml* like that

```
 import QtQuick 2.1

Item {
    property alias model: dataModel


//! [0]

ListModel{
    id: dataModel
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "0"; height: "-700.114"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "1"; height: "-698.214"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "2"; height: "-695.955"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "3"; height: "-706.116"; }
    [...]

     }
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a introduction, it is usually preferred to keep your data format generic, instead of QML code. QML is meant for GUI, and it is important to avoid mixing application logic and GUI code if you want to keep your code generic, and maintainable. You could use JSON format for instance, and load it from C++ or if you still from to load it from QML, you can use `JSON.parse` javascript function directly.

That being said, you can put your QML model in a separated .qml file, for instance:

`DataModel.qml`

```
ListModel {
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "0"; height: "-700.114"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "1"; height: "-698.214"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "2"; height: "-695.955"; }
    ListElement{ longitude: "0"; latitude: "3"; height: "-706.116"; }
 }
```

And then use the [`Qt.createComponent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method) method to create a component, and then the object, which you could use that way:

```
function loadModel() {
    // Create the component
    var component = Qt.createComponent("DataModel.qml");

    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        // Instantiate the object given a parent
        var model = component.createObject(qmlParentId);

        // Assign the newly created object to your property
        root.model = model
    }
}
```

Once loaded, your model will be available.

Comment: but i need put the text from txt file to ListModel{}

Comment: Then the closest is "Qt.createQmlObject" from QML which takes a string. But there is no such thing as "put the text from txt file". And except if you have really good reasons (which you might have), this approach seems flawed to me.